# How to make a hr apppear when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button on my website that changes the theme of it. I would like to know how to make it so when you click that button a line appears under the navigation bar. My code:
http://pastebin.com/HUXALHmb

Comment: A line or a horizontal rule? Also what button are do you mean? What does this button do at the moment?

Comment: I would like a horizontal rule along the bottom of the navigation bar. At the moment the button (top left: "Light Switch") changes the background-color of the page from grey to dark grey

Comment: @Amorris Do you want an HR or just the border effect?

Answer (score 2):

You can also place an hr wherever you want it:

```
<hr id="line" style="display: none;"/>
```

And then you can call it to show when a button is clicked (jQuery):

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
    $('#line').css("display", "inherit");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ad css styling via jquery:

```
$("#lightswitch").click(function(){      
 $(".nav").css("border", "1px solid yellow");
 });
```

or insert a hr Tag after the nav :

```
$("#lightswitch").click(function(){
      $( ".nav" ).append( "<hr>");
});
```